# New and Lost in 15.04 Ubuntu

Tags: 15.04

New To Ubuntu but got it installed. Ver 15.04 . how does the software center work. I want to ad items to the menu. I did get one to be installed but don't know what I did.
??????
Jerry

Comment: We do not know what you did either. Please add more details to your question.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Answer (score 1):

You launch the software center, search for software, select "install" if you found something you want, enter your password and it'll be installed after it downloaded the applications you want to install.

After you installed graphical applications, they usually go straight to you launcher (the bar on the left from which you can launch applications). If it isn't there, press `super` (also called "Windows Key" since it has a Windows symbol on most keyboards) and type in the name of the application or something related to it (like "internet" for the browser) to make it show up. If it does show up, you simply take the symbol and drag it into the launcher. If you want to remove something from the launcher, right-click it and select "unlock from launcher".